# How to align an image inside a DIV without adding new classes using CSS

Tags: css, alignment, center

I need to align the image to Center inside the DIV but I cannot add new classes. It is possible to do this? I've tried but no clue until now.

```
<div class="thumbnail visible-phone">
    <a href="/#"><img src="some.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Some clues?

Best Regards,

Comment: What do you want to use to do this, inline CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.thumbnail {
  text-align: center;
}
```

That will center all the text in the div.

If you want to center JUST the image and leave everything else left aligned,

```
.thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or just add a quick inline style

```
<div class="thumbnail visible-phone">
<a href="/#"><img src="some.jpg" style="text-align: center"></a>
```

Comment: Except that doesn't work... Please test your solution before posting.